# Can we change svgicon color when using with <mat-icon> (angular material)

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material, angular5

So I have an svg icon, I am using angular material to display it and wanted to change the color on hover but so far I haven't been able to do that.
Here's the code for reference:

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="menu"></mat-icon>
```

The icon comes up however when I try,

```
<mat-icon class="color" svgIcon="menu"></mat-icon>
```

and in css part

```
.color:hover, .color:active{
color: black;
fill: black;
}
```

It doesn't work.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 33):

Solved it myself this morning, what I did basically was opened the svg file with a text editor and there was a fill property at the end of the long "Path" attributes, I simply deleted that part and now it works awesome.

example(before):-

```
<path d="M47.713,274.096c0,3.866,3.134,7,7,7s7-3.134,7-7v-64.653l87.584-`66.53v52.38c0,3.866" fill="#ffffff";/>`
```

After:-

```
<path d="M47.713,274.096c0,3.866,3.134,7,7,7s7-3.134,7-7v-64.653l87.584-`66.53v52.38c0,3.866"/>
```

now everything works, and hover works too... Thanks a lot for still looking into it.

Comment: Only answer that has worked out of many other posts!! thank you

Comment: Awesome answer!

Answer (score 0):

SVG icons are black by default unless otherwise specified, the code you posted seems to be working, try changing the color property on hover to `red` and see if you can see the change.